# pylint_django "Instance of 'ForeignKey' has no ... member"

Tags: python, django, django-models, pylint

I'm working on a project in python with django and recently I decided to modify the way the models were stored in one of the apps. With the help of django documentation, I deleted the models.py file and created a models folder in which I put all my models in files and created a _*init*_.py file in which I import all my models. This solution works but now pylint no longer seems to understand ForeignKeys.

this is my app tree:

- apps

  - myapp

    - models

      - _*init*_.py
      - mymodel.py
      - mymodel2.py

if i run pylint i can see some E1101. let's take an example:

i have a model subnet in subnet.py:

```py
class Subnet(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom + "(" + self.cidr + ")"

    net = models.ForeignKey("Network", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="subnets")

    def get_parent_cidr(self):
        return self.net.cidr
```

this model have a reference to the network models in network.py:

```py
class Network(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.name + " - " + self.nom + " - " + str(self.cidr)
    cidr = models.CharField(max_length=18)
```

this network object have a cidr field, all seems to be fine but when i run pylint with the pylint_django plugin, this one send me an error:

`project/apps/myapp/models/subnet.py:74:15: E1101: Instance of 'ForeignKey' has no 'cidr' member (no-member)`

What did I do wrong and how can I correct this error?

Comment: That is because pylint does not understand the meta-programming on Django's part.

Comment: The `pylint_django` module checks if the module ends with `models`: https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint-django/blob/master/pylint_django/transforms/foreignkey.py#L99-L118